# another server's cache for ''member''

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How to make that if my bot is on a server it will keep the cache of these users, so that it works on another server.

ex: use the userinfo command with the user ID of that server x (where my bot is) in another server y

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) ||
message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.displayName === args[0]) || message.member;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Client.users.cache.get(user_id)` will allow you to get the User object of anyone by their ID as long as your bot is in a guild with them.

`Guild.members.cache` only holds GuildMember objects from members of that `Guild`.